# I couldn't understand this structure 住んでいた時

Tags: syntax

私はローマに住んでいた時に子供でした。

I didn't understand "住んでいた時". I would like a explanation about this structure and a translation.

Comment: `私はローマに住んでいた時に子供でした。` <- This sentence sounds a bit unnatural... (I'd rather say something like ローマに住んでいたとき、私はまだ子供でした or 私は、ローマに住んでいたとき(に)はまだ子供でした) Did you find it in your book/textbook?

Comment: Without は after 時に, it sounds like "It's when I lived in Rome that I was a child".

Comment: Thank you for the answers, they helped me a lot! Your example sentences were very helpful, chocolate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 私はローマに住んでいた時に子供でした。
>   When I was in Rome, I was a child.

とき(に) means "when ～". See [this article](http://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/toki-in-japanese.html).

As you can see in the link, とき here is just a noun that means "time". So once you have learned how to modify a noun (e.g., using an adjective or a relative clause), you can use various ways to say "when ～".

As pointed out in the comment section, this sentence is a bit unnatural because the main subject (私は) and the main predicate (子供でした) are far apart.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you for your answer, the link and your remarks, they are really useful!

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, the sentence sounds weird. To answer your question:

住む is the verb "to live".

= > 住んで is the "te" form of the verb — a verb form used in many ways.

= > 住んでいる is the "te-iru" form of the verb. This means "living".

= > 住んでいた is the past tense of the "te-iru" form of the verb. This means "was living".

時 is simply "time".

Therefore 住んでいた時 means "the time when I was living".